# Merge single- and multi-band rasters with stars

Tags: raster, r, stack, stars

I can easily use `c()` to merge two single band rasters or two multi-band rasters using the R package `stars`, however, when I try merging a single band raster with a multi band raster, I get the error `Error in attr(x, "dimensions")[[along]] : subscript out of bounds`.

```
library(stars)

# single band raster
x_single <- read_stars(system.file("tif/lc.tif", package = "stars"))
# multi band raster
x_multi <- c(x_single, x_single, along = "band")

# merging single band and single band is ok
c(x_single, x_single, along = "band")
# merging multi-band and multi-band is ok
c(x_multi, x_multi, along = "band")

# merging single and multi band fails
c(x_single, x_multi, along = "band")
#> Error in combine_dimensions(dots, along_dim) : 
#>   dimensions of element 1 and 2 are not identical
c(x_multi, x_single, along = "band")
#> Error in attr(x, "dimensions")[[along]] : subscript out of bounds
```

It appears that I need to add a `bands` dimension to `x_single`, but I have no idea how to do that.